# Excel vba: type mismatch error on Array date format

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, format

Can someone help me on this error please..

[image]
[image]

getting type mismatch error on Array date format in the line mentioned below.
mykey = arr(i, 7) & format(arr(i, 11), "|dd-mmm-yy")     'job name & start date

Please help me on this.
Code:

```
     Dim T_Start, T_Stop, Shift_Start, Shift_Stop, Result    
     Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     Set lo = Sheets("temp_sheet").ListObjects("TBL_Jobs")   
     arr = lo.DataBodyRange.Value2     'read that table to an array
     ReDim Result(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)


     '1st ROUND : find last status at the end of the shift
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)     'loop through data
            T_Start = arr(i, 11) + arr(i, 12)     'timestamp end of job
            T_Stop = arr(i, 14) + arr(i, 15)     'timestamp end of job
          
            mykey = arr(i, 7) & format(arr(i, 11), "\|dd-mmm-yy")     'job name & start date
          
        If arr(i, 11) = arr(i, 14) Then
          
            If T_Stop <= arr(i, 11) + TimeSerial(15, 0, 0) Then     'job must end before next day 3PM
               If Not dict.exists(mykey) Then
                    dict(mykey) = Array(T_Stop, arr(i, 10))
               Else
                    If dict(mykey)(0) < T_Stop Then dict(mykey) = Array(T_Stop, arr(i, 10))     '---> for that job and that startdate, the last endmoment & status
               End If
            Else
               Result(i, 1) = "Notwithinshift"
          End If
     
                    
          Else
          
            If T_Stop <= arr(i, 11) + 1 + TimeSerial(15, 0, 0) Then     'job must end before next day 3PM
                 If Not dict.exists(mykey) Then
                      dict(mykey) = Array(T_Stop, arr(i, 10))
                 Else
                      If dict(mykey)(0) < T_Stop Then dict(mykey) = Array(T_Stop, arr(i, 10))     '---> for that job and that startdate, the last endmoment & status
                 End If
            Else
                 Result(i, 1) = "Notwithinshift"
            End If
     
     
        End If
     
    Next

     '2nd ROUND : add status corresponding with status "end of shift"
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)     'loop through data
          If Len(Result(i, 1)) = 0 Then     'no blocking conditions
            mykey = arr(i, 1) & format(arr(i, 11), "\|dd-mmm-yy")    'key within dictionary
            Result(i, 1) = dict(mykey)(1)     'last known status
          End If
     Next

     lo.ListColumns("Final Status").DataBodyRange.Value = Result     'write array to listobject

End Sub
```

Getting the issue in another line.. could you please help..

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve].  That means we need details.  We need to be able to reproduce the error to be able to help.  Also Code should be text and not a picture.

Comment: You will at least need to tell us how `mykey` and `arr()` are declared, and how `arr` is populated.

Comment: updated my query.. please check and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the table and ran your macro. It compiles just fine and writes result to column 'Final Status'.

Looks like the error on line

```
mykey = arr(i, 7) & format(arr(i, 11), "|dd-mmm-yy")
```

could be due to formatting issue. In table column 7 (`arr(i, 7)`) I set the format to "Time". Your picture only shows 9 columns, but set your format in column 11 to "Short Date", it worked for me.

Comment: That works really perfect however I got the issue in another line now.. Pasted the screenshot in my post.. Please check.

Comment: could you please help @Havard Kleven

Comment: I’d need to recreate it again - I’ll get back to you

Comment: Sure.. will wait for your reply.. Thanks again..

Comment: I'd need further details on your error. Recreated your file/table with above macro again - ran just fine without any error. What does your data in the row your error occurs look like?

Comment: It validates the End Time of each job and if the end time is 3 PM or earlier then the script will copy the data from "Status" Column and Paste it in "Final Status" Column. If the End time is post 3PM of that Job then it will mention as "Notwithinshift" in "Final Status" Column.

Comment: could you please help me on this ??

Comment: Hi - still can not replicate your error.. :/ works perfectly for me. Any more details you can provide in your question?

Comment: I will try again with new sheet and will let you know about the results.. But your answer helped me though. Appreciate your help on this.